# XML/JSON should return FK Integer or FK string value?

Tags: php, xml, json

I need to make a script which will fetch data from one table and produce XML or JSON response. Now, the table has data from other tables (FKs) represented by `int` value.

Would it be wrong to make a response which returns both FKs and its values from other tables? I am not sure what is the bets programming practice.

For example, a response could look like this (XML)

```
<item>
      <guid>1738291029</guid>
      <title>Some title</title>
      <link>http://www.site.info</link>
      <description>A description</description>
      <id>4</id>                   //FK int from main table!
      <category>News</category>    //String value from other table!
</item>
```

In here, I return the FK int value and its corresponding value from the linking table.

Comment: Best practise is to return suitable data for the desired purpose, not to return data based on the way it is stored.

Comment: Well I need FK's string value for display purpose, and I need FK int value for POST request.

Comment: So you need both pieces of data for the desired purpose? Therefore the data you send should include both pieces of data.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. I got this from the first post and now I see my comment looked like another question.

Comment: @Quentin Please make a reply and I'll mark you as the answer